# Dota 2 workshop content keeps downloading in the background

Tags: pc, dota-2

I checked online for solutions , I unsubscribed all the workshop items, I unchecked all the dlc on the list . The issue still persists . It keeps downloading 5-20 KB files in the background and it never stops. This causes lag spikes in game .

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: How do you know they are file*s*, and of that particular size? Is it because you know where they're downloaded?

Comment: this is bug in steam update system, those workshop updates often get stuck and then consume near 100% of cpu. you can possibly mitigate this by turning off background updates.